# How to move points with the mouse in a Julia plot?

Tags: julia

I want to learn Julia for computational physics and simulations, and I want to make an interactive plot where the user can drag a point with the mouse and that will update plots that depend on the point. For example, I have a point `A` and I plot a line through the origin and the point `A`. I want the user to be able to drag the point around, and the line updates to follow this point. How can I achieve something like this?
Since I am new to Julia, I am still figuring out what IDE would fit my needs best, but I'd probably go with VSCode or Pluto, if that makes any difference in the code.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotlyJS.jl accessible via Plots.jl could make that possible.  Also look at Makie: https://docs.makie.org/stable/explanations/nodes/